# Arduino Video player?

Tags: arduino-mega, sd-card, tft

I want to play video from SD card   by using arduino mega 2560 and TFT 3.2" touch screen is it possible ?

if yes please tell me.

thanks in adavance

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: @Majenko is it possible to play video from mobile via USB cable

Comment: You mean watch a video on your phone? Sure. Plug the SD card into your phone and open the video.

Comment: No ,is it possible to play video from mobile  on arduino  display via USB cable

Comment: If you can't play it from a local card then what makes you think you can play it from a remote connection?

Comment: It is not possible to play video on an Arduino from *any* source. The closest you could get would be to cycle through a set of images somewhat slowly.

Comment: The easiest way to understand why this is not possible is to "do the numbers", i.e. calculate the max frame rate for the TFT and image read from SD when using an Arduino. Even simply trying to read a file without decompression and writing to the TFT with give a very low frame rate.

Answer (score 1):

An ATMEGA2560 has no enough computational power to perform on-the-fly decoding, even at resolutions as low as 160x128 pixels and low frame rates.

The best you can hope for is a 20 fps, 16 bpp, 160x128 pixel video, directly streamed from the SD card, uncompressed (800kB/s), if the MCU runs at 16MHz. Even with such low specs, you'll have to use a trick, to implement a direct peripheral to peripheral transfer.

We made a guide here for the Arduino Uno (i.e. ATMEGA328P), but it should work also for ATMEGA2560 with little modifications: https://next-hack.com/index.php/2017/08/14/how-to-play-a-video-on-arduino-uno-46-playing-a-20-fps-animation-from-sd-card/

On the same link you'll find also the youtube links for a video guide.